# Eror occurs when install nuxt and create app

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

Cannot instal nuxt and create app.
I used https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation and https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app for creating app but  this error occurs:
"create-nuxt-app"
is not internal or external
command executed by a program or batch file.

````
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nuxt
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-nuxt-app "hacker-news"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-03T06_03_59_129Z-debug-0.log```
Please help!

PS: node js and npm are installed
````

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

1. npm cache clean --force (sudo if needed)
2. npm install

Comment: Please accept your own answer when you can.